# How to update div without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to make a `div` update in app script, but since the code is written in the html it can only be run once. Is there any way to refresh the `div` without page refresh?

```js
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Data1"),sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Data2");

function doGet(e){
  var tmp=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("main");
  tmp.list1=sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues(),tmp.list2=sheet2.getRange(1,1,sheet2.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();;
  return tmp.evaluate().setTitle("WhatsUp");
}
```

```css
.old{
        background-color:lightgreen;
        border-radius:10px;
        }
.msg{
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
        border-radius:10px;
        padding:2px;
        transition:1s ease;
        margin:5px;
        position:relative;
        left:-100%;
      }
```

```html
<div class="old">
    <h3>You</h3>
    <? for(var i=0;i<list1.length;i++){ ?>
  <div class="msg"><?= list1[i]; ?></div>
    <? }?>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="old2">
    <h3>Other User</h3>
  <? for(var j=0;j<list2.length;j++){ ?>
  <div class="msg"><?= list2[j]; ?></div>
    <? }?>
```

There are 2 web pages both save and read the data from an excel document, therefore I would like the div which displayes the messages to be updated periodically (add or remove the black `divs`) without page refresh.

> Whatsup?

**Full code below**

```js
//code.gs
var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm";
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Data1"),sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Data2");

function doGet(e){
  var tmp=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("main");
  tmp.list1=sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues(),tmp.list2=sheet2.getRange(1,1,sheet2.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();;
  return tmp.evaluate().setTitle("WhatsUp");
}
function send(msg){
  sheet.appendRow([msg]);
}
function clearYouLast(){sheet.deleteRow(sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length);}
function clearUserLast(){sheet2.deleteRow(sheet2.getDataRange().getValues().length);}
function clearYou(){sheet.clearContents();}
function clearUser(){sheet2.clearContents();}
function clearAll(){clearYou();clearUser();}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      .old{
        background-color:lightgreen;
        border-radius:10px;
        }
      .up{
        border-radius:50%;
        background-color:lime;
        position:fixed;
        top:70%;
        right:10%;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      .msg{
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
        border-radius:10px;
        padding:2px;
        transition:1s ease;
        margin:5px;
        position:relative;
        left:-100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="load();">
    <h1>WhatsUP</h1>
    <form onsubmit="return send()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Message here" id="msg">
    <button class="send" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  <div class="old">
    <h3>You</h3>
    <!--This code needs to be reran-->
    <? for(var i=0;i<list1.length;i++){ ?>
  <div class="msg"><?= list1[i]; ?></div>
    <? }?>
    <!--As you may see when running the above it creates multiple div elements
    with the class of (msg)-->
    <!--What I mean by rerunning is that if the list1 contains less items the number of divs with class (msg) should reduce AND IF the number of items in list1 increases the number of divs with class (msg) should increase-->
    <!--End-->
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="old2">
    <h3>Other User</h3>
  <? for(var j=0;j<list2.length;j++){ ?>
  <div class="msg"><?= list2[j]; ?></div>
    <? }?>
  </div>
  <button onclick="google.script.run.clearYouLast()">Delete</button>
  <button onclick="google.script.run.clearYou()">Delete Your Messages</button>
  <button onclick="google.script.run.clearAll()">Delete All Messages</button>
  <!--<button onclick="google.script.run.clearUser()" >Delete Your Messages</button>-->
  <img onclick="upload()" class="up" alt="Upload file" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/sarahdesign/sarahdesign1509/sarahdesign150901050/44517597-%EC%97%85%EB%A1%9C%EB%93%9C-%EB%B2%84%ED%8A%BC-%EC%97%85%EB%A1%9C%EB%93%9C-%EC%95%84%EC%9D%B4%EC%BD%98.jpg">

    <script>
      function send(){
        google.script.run.send(document.getElementById("msg").value);
        document.getElementById("msg").value="";
        return false
      }
      function upload(){
        if(confirm("Upload file and get Data Url send the url!")==true){
          window.open("https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri","","width=200");}
        
      }
      function load(){
        var el=document.getElementsByClassName("msg");
        for(let i=0;i<el.length;i++){el[i].style.left='0%';}
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You can download vs code extension Live Server or switch to react

Comment: Use `google.script.run` instead of templates.

Comment: Screenshots of the webpage as well as a sample data can help us elaborate more on what you would want to accomplish.

Comment: Im creating two website that saves data to an excel file and are then displayed as individual `divs`.

Comment: @Dumdum Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that you had updated your question. I apologize for this. When I saw your updated question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When I saw your initial question, I could understand that you want to update the tag of div without refreshing the page.

Comment: @Dumdum But, when I saw your updated question, unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. So at first, I have to correctly understand your updated question. So in this case, I think that my answer was not useful for your updated question. Because my answer is for your initial question. So I have to delete my answer. This is due to my poor English skill that I couldn't understand your updated question from your initial question. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Dumdum In the current stage, I think that it is required to correctly understand your updated question. So can I ask you about the detail of your updated question? By this, I would like to try to understand your updated question. By the way, about `There are 2 web pages both save and read the data from an excel document`, where is the XLSX file?

Comment: @Tanaike Google sheets file. The sheet is stored in the variable url in code.gs file. Both the web pages are identical (I've given the code of the first web page in my question). Im trying to mimic whatsapp. Your English doent seem bad to me..

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike I would like to run the piece of code with a click of a button. `<? for(var i=0;i<list1.length;i++){ ?>
  <div class="msg"><?= list1[i]; ?></div>
    <? }?>`. This is basically what i need it to do. Thanks.